# Make file suddenly confused about an empty target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My Makefile, stripped down to the bare minimum for illustrating this problem, looks like:

```
CC := cc
CFLAGS :=

AIOLIB := -lrt
MATHLIB := -lm

LIBS := $(LIBS) $(AIOLIB) $(MATHLIB)

CAW_EXECS := cawser_tim
ALL_EXECS := $(CAW_EXECS)

# Targets:

calc_and_write: cawser_tim    # < --- make gets confused with this target

# ========================= CALC AND WRITE ===================================
cawser_tim: calc_and_write_timing.c
        -$(CC) $(INCS) $(DEFS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

clean:
        -rm $(ALL_EXECS)
```

Usually the `calc_and_write` target would have several prerequisites besides `cawser_tim`.  I've stripped it down for illustration purposes.  'make' builds `cawser_tim` with no problem.  But then it gets the idea that, in addition to `cawser_tim` it is somehow supposed to also produce a file `calc_and_write` and tries to do so according to

```
cc     calc_and_write.c cawser_tim   -o calc_and_write
```

which, of course, fails completely.  In the larger `Makefile` of which this is a part, the entire build comes to a halt.

Now, I solved this problem by introducing a `.PHONY` target:

```
.PHONY : calc_and_write clean
calc_and_write: cawser_tim
```

which is not something I hardly ever do.  (Shame on me, I guess.)

So I solved this problem, but here's my question: I never, ever see this kind of thing happen.  In my larger `Makefile`, I actually have other empty targets similar to `calc_and_write` that build just fine.  Can anyone tell me why make is suddenly so "sensitive" to this one target?  BTW, there is no file actually named "calc_and_write" in my directory; that, at least, is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not relevant whether there's a file `calc_and_write`.  What's important is whether there's a file `calc_and_write.c`.  There apparently is such a file.

Because your target `calc_and_write` is not phony, make will try to build it.  If it can't find any rule to build it then it will just say "oh well" and not do anything.  But if it CAN find a rule to use, then it will run the rule.

In this case make finds its built-in rule for building a program from a source file:

```
% : %.c
        ...
```

and it sees that there is a file named `calc_and_write.c`, and so this built-in rule matches, and so make tries to use it to create the program `calc_and_write`.